# navigation between fields in html

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have in my page the following elements in sequence:

input-text  link  input-text   link

How to navigate using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key from one input to the other input, jumping the links ?

Answer (score 4):

You can control the order in which elements are accessed with the tab key by setting the [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) property in your elements:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />

<a href="#" tabindex="3">link</a>

<input type="text" tabindex="2" />

<a href="#" tabindex="4">link</a>
```

This will cause the first `input` to receive keyboard-focus first, then the second `input` followed by the links. Here's a [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GfGYL/).

Comment: Thanks. I just set the links tabindex to -1.

Answer (score 1):

I think  the [`tabindex`](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/HTML/controll_tab_order.php) property may be what you're looking for.